# Is Bhargava multidimensional matrices and elliptic curves methods applying also to finite fields?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

There are a bunch of papers of Bhargava et al. [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.1002.pdf) and [2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0233.pdf) where they use multidimensional matrices and hyperdetermimant to derive theorems about the average ranks of genus 1 or 2 curves over rational fields. Are these multidimensional matrices techniques also valid for elliptic curves over finite fields?

Comment: Why did you ask this again?

Comment: I added references as requested. What's wrong now ? :)

Comment: You should edit your question, not reask it.

Comment: I edited adding the links as requested...